# regarding privacy policy for windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I don't have any personal website or url to specify in my app for privacy policy. Is there any alternate for me to specify the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, maybe you can create a blogger page or something but you do need an webpage to define your privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Heuer has a good article on using Azure Websites to create a free marketing website with a privacy policy. Check it out at [Using Azure Web Sites to market your Windows App](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/09/26/use-azure-free-web-site-for-windows-store-app-content.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [Common Windows Store certification errors: 4.1 Your app must comply with privacy requirements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/15/common-windows-store-certification-errors-4-1-your-app-must-comply-with-privacy-requirements.aspx) discusses the privacy policy requirement.  It gives tips on how to turn off the Internet capability if you're not using network functionality so you won't need a privacy policy, what to include in the privacy policy, some free sites where you can create a blog to host your privacy policy ([WordPress](http://wordpress.com/signup/?ref=bigassbutton) or [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com)), and where you need to provide the privacy policy in your app.